# node js [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

I just write two similar code like these, but only material can run and the order has the error "[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" when I submit the form

order.js

```
pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            connection.query('SELECT customerid FROM order_table WHERE customerid =?', [customerid],function(err,rows){
                if(err){
                    res.render('error',{
                        message:err.message,
                        error:err
                    });
                }
         /*
            if(rows.length>=1){
                res.render('operation/order',{warn:"You have already order!"});  

            }else{
                */   
                    var cmd="INSERT INTO order_table(customerid,customerName,phonenumber,productid,amount,orderday,deadlineday) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        connection.query(cmd,[customerid,customerName,phonenumber,productid,amount,orderday,deadlineday],function(err,result){
                            console.log(req.body);
                            if(err){
                                res.redirect('/order');
                            //return next();
                            }else{
                                res.render('operation/order_redirect');
                            }
                    });
            //}
            });

        });
    //callback(err, result);
    connection.release();
});

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Show us some code so that we can help you

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Answer (score 0):

> The error comes when you are trying send the response though it is already sent.

As I can see you have not returned the state when there is an error. So use `return` to return the state so that below code does not execute.

```
if(err){
   return res.render('error',{
         message:err.message,
         error:err
    });
}
```

> Why this error occurs:

---

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. ([Find more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client))

---

Answer (score 0):

There's an error caught in you `if` block, but your `if` block doesn't have an `else` block, so the code followed by the `if` block is always executed whether an error occurred or whether not. So `res.render` is executed and a response is sent to the client, the rest of the code is being executed right after and when calling `redirect` headers are being set and you cannot do this after a response was already sent to the client.

Just add `else` to the rest of your code as follows:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            connection.query('SELECT customerid FROM order_table WHERE customerid =?', [customerid],function(err,rows){
                if(err){
                    res.render('error',{
                        message:err.message,
                        error:err
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var cmd="INSERT INTO order_table(customerid,customerName,phonenumber,productid,amount,orderday,deadlineday) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        connection.query(cmd,[customerid,customerName,phonenumber,productid,amount,orderday,deadlineday],function(err,result){
                            console.log(req.body);
                            if(err){
                                res.redirect('/order');
                            //return next();
                            }else{
                                res.render('operation/order_redirect');
                            }
                    });
            }
            });

        });
    //callback(err, result);
    connection.release();
});

module.exports = router;
```